# Enabling API access for GE/PE Edition: How to Append Partner Token to clientId for SOAP Call Salesforce?

Tags: api, soap, professional-edition, group-edition

I have received a partner token from Salesforce which needs to be appended in SOAP header, I am using following code to authenticate a valid session, but I am not sure where I need to append partner token. Following is my code in Java.

> ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
>   config.setAuthEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/");
>   config.setServiceEndpoint(salesforceUserCredentials.getServerURL());
>   config.setSessionId(salesforceUserCredentials.getSessionId());
>   connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config); logger.info("Connection
>   Status: "+connection);
>
> GetUserInfoResult userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Partner Token is set in the [`CallOption.client`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) field.

At a guess from your example code:

```
connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config);

connection.CallOptionsValue = new CallOptions();
connection.CallOptionsValue.client = "YourPartnerToken/";

logger.info("Connection Status: "+connection);
GetUserInfoResult userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();
```